# How to solve a fourth order nonlinear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How can I solve the following 4th order nonlinear ODE:

$$ y^{(4)}+A(y'''y-y''y')-By''=0 $$

$$y'(0.5)=-\alpha Cy''(0.5),\\
y'(-0.5)=\alpha Cy''(-0.5),\\
y(0.5)=0,\quad y(-0.5)=0 $$

Would you please suggest any method that will give an approximate (or numerical) solution for this ODE.

Comment: I believe Runge-Kutta may help (numerical method). There are others, see a book on numerical analysis (unfortunately I can't recommend any)

Comment: This is a boundary value problem (BVP), thus you need to use a BVP solver like bvp4c in matlab or scipy.integrate.solve_bvp in python or similar.